# Should I add a test.log to my repo and if yes, how to run Jest in a way that won't output time durations next to tests?

Tags: jestjs

I want to add a `test.log` from Jest output to my repo, so I can see on each commit what was the test suite like at that moment, and to have an overview in PR review of how test names and/or layout/structure changed (I will have a CI/CD job that on push will not only run all tests but also compare the tests output with the `test.log` inside pushed commit and fail if those logs differ).

Now I get this:

```
...
  for request with additional unknown field
    ✓ should 400, not alter database and return message that explains error cause (46 ms)
...
```

But I want this:

```
...
  for request with additional unknown field
    ✓ should 400, not alter database and return message that explains error cause
...
```

I can't find an option to run Jest like that. I'm running it with `--verbose` so I get the list of all tests, but it includes time durations. Is there an additinal or alternative option I can use?

Also, is my idea even valid? I have not found any other project yet that does such thing but it seems to me like a good idea, very similar to snapshots or visual testing of UI using screenshots or tools like [chromatic](https://www.chromatic.com/) + [storybook](https://storybook.js.org/).

I have thousands of lines of testing code and use a few techniques for making those less redundant (reasonably) and compact, e.g. parametrized tests. Additionally, sometimes I do a little reorganization of tests layout or fix/improve test names. Therefore, such `test.log` that clearly shows what is the end result of a change in tests structure and naming, would be very helpful in PR review IMO. Am I right?

I know that normally we do not include logs in a repo, but I want to make an exception for that scenario because it makes work much more convenient, I don't see any downsides yet and I don't know CI/CD tools that would give me such a diff of tests suite layout (+why would I need such tools if just adding this `test.log` to git + mentioned above CI/CD task handles it well).

My guess is that the idea is valid but Jest does not support such stuff so I have to parse the output myself and remove the time durations.

I checked some blogs, SO and Jest documentation and it seems like nobody had this idea or issue before so I want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious here.

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--listtests?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it outputs only a list of files, not each actual test, even with `--verbose`.

Comment: Seems to have been that way for a while: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47722048/getting-a-list-of-tests-run-with-jest-without-running-suites#comment118371823_47722048

Comment: @jonrsharpe could not find that one, thank you. I will remove the time durations from log with some script in that case :/. I also wanted to know if the idea in general is good but I guess that if it works for me and actually helps then why not.